# Checking if a web application hosted in IIS is accessed by any user

Tags: iis, web-applications

I have a web application developed in ASP.net hosted on IIS in our network(Box1). We have migrated this application to a different environment(Box2). We have modified all the applications to call application Box2 instead of Box1.

As this application is being called from various applications, I want to check if the application in Box1 is called by any application.

Is there any easy way to monitor this without doing any code changes.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the IIS logs on Box1 to see what accesses occur...

and/or setup a permanent redirect in IIS from Box1 to Box2.

**EDIT - another option:**

Put a static html page on Box1 instead of the app explaining that it has been moved to a new URL (Box2) and include that URL...

IF you want to do it the hard way you can just shutdown the app on Box1 and see whoever comes up with an error saysing that they can't access the app...

Comment: Thanks Yahia. I cannot redirect from Box1 to Box2 due to the fact that there are lot of querystring parameters that got changed etc.

Comment: Shutting down is not an option as users will make noise if they don't see the page. They don't care if its coming from box1 or box2

Comment: ok... but checking the IIS Logs doesn't need any code changes and doesn't make noise with the users and lets you know what accesses your app on Box1... for another option see my EDIT above...